# Why is making a shared pointer from a reference copies the object?

Tags: c++, copy, pass-by-reference, shared-ptr

I intended to have a constructor to accept references and then create pointers to the objects passed as references and store these pointers in a field. However, for some reason the way I did it, copies are being created, and I don't see why:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

// the class with the field of pointers
template<class T, class... Types>
class C
{

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> mem; // the field of pointers

public:
    C(T& t, Types&... args)
      // make pointers to the objects passed by reference and store them in mem
      : mem{ std::make_shared<T>(t), std::make_shared<T>(args)... }
    {

        // to demonstrate that the pointers point to copies, alter one of the objects (subscript operator expected)
        (*mem[0])[0] = 10;


        // demonstrate the effect on the local copies
        std::cout << "vectors in mem:" << "\n";
        for (const auto& x : mem) {
            for (const auto& y : *x) {
                std::cout << y << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> v2{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> v3{ 1, 2, 3 };

    // make an object of type C with some vectors to store pointers to in field mem
    C<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>> c(v1, v2, v3);

    // demonstrate that original vectors are unaltered
    std::cout << "original vectors:"<< "\n";

    for (const auto& y : v1) {
        std::cout << y << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    for (const auto& y : v2) {
        std::cout << y << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    for (const auto& y : v3) {
        std::cout << y << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

What am I missing here? Where is the copying happening and why?

Comment: Accepting and taking ownership of a *reference* is a bad and error prone idea.

Comment: I normally have everything const, I just needed to unconst it all to demonstrate the copying.

Comment: It has nothing to do with const. Your code can easily crash from what is *idiomatic* C++.

Comment: ok, but how else would I store the objects passed to the constructor without copying them?

Comment: Accept a smart pointer to the object to being with. The caller is then aware of the ownership semantics from the API itself.

Comment: ok I see. (I find that an ugly interface though, but I see why it's necessary)

Comment: You get used to it. The benefits far outweigh the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is `std::make_shared<T>(t)`. `make_shared` will call the constructor of `T` that accepts the parameters it's being given. And you give it a `T` lvalue by reference.

Naturally the copy constructor is called. And it's a good thing. Had you created a shared pointer *to the very object you are passed*, your code will probably be a heap of undefined behavior.

I suggest you accept the parameter by smart pointer instead. It makes the ownership semantics clear to the user of your class from the API itself.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I missing here? Where is the copying happening and why?

To answer the question literally, from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared):

> `template< class T, class... Args >`
>   `shared_ptr<T> make_shared( Args&&... args );`
>   Constructs an object of type `T` and wraps it in a `std::shared_ptr` using `args` as the parameter list for the constructor of `T`.

In your case, `std::make_shared<T>(t)` (`t` being a `T&`) invokes `T::T(T const&)` and builds a *copy* of `t`. An incorrect solution would be to create your `std::shared_ptr`s yourself without the help of `std::make_shared` ... but in this case you would create smart pointers to potentially statically allocated objects. And this is *bad*, like *Undefined Behaviour* bad.

A better solution is to simply avoid creating smart pointers to objects passed by reference, as it may come to a surprise to the caller. Better take smart pointers:

```
C(std::shared_ptr<T> t, std::shared_ptr<Types> ...args) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: This will result in deleting objects that were not dynamically allocated.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley And that's exactly what OP is asking. They might expect the caller to give references to dynamically allocated objects. This is why making smart pointer from reference is a bad idea.

Comment: The only reason the OP is asking that is because he doesn't understand the purpose of smart pointers. If he expected the caller to give references to dynamically allocated objects, he would have done that in his own code. Your answer doesn't attempt to correct that misunderstanding at all. I'd suggest you replace "(bad) solution" with "incorrect solution". Or simply leave that bit out entirely.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley you're right, I hadn't read the usage they have done of their class. Editing...

Answer (score 2):

`std::make_shared<T>` allocates a single chunk of memory large enough to store the object of type T (initializing it with the passed parameters, if any), and attached to it a control block to manage the shared ownership (like keeping the object reference count, etc.).

```
+---------------+
| Control block |
|               |
+ ............. +
|  Object (T)   |
|               |
+---------------+
```

So, even if you pass a *reference* to an object, `make_shared` will create its own "deep" *copy* (constructing its object copy in place in a section of the memory block allocated as described above).