# Fail to make a shared pointer from a reference

Tags: c++, reference

The main question here is: Can I make a shared pointer using a reference?

In the following code, class `AnimalList` implements a container that holds a vector of shared pointers to all types derived from `Animal`. In order to push items into the container, class `AnimalList` has two methods, one allows a reference and the other accepts a shared pointer.

Clearly, creating a share pointer via a reference fails to deliver the desired result. See Segmentation fault at line [5].

I am aware of the [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550227/why-is-making-a-shared-pointer-from-a-reference-copies-the-object) that creating a shared pointer out of a reference shall be avoided. But I don't quite understand why creating a shared pointer via reference in this way fails. What should be the proper approach if this is possible at all?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>


class Animal {
private:
    std::string type = "Animal";
public:
    Animal() {}
    virtual std::string get_type() { return type; }
};


class Bird : public Animal {
private:
    std::string type = "Bird";
public:
    Bird() {}
    std::string get_type() { return type; }
};


class Mammal : public Animal {
private:
    std::string type = "Mammal";
public:
    Mammal() {}
    std::string get_type() { return type; }
};


class AnimalList {
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Animal> > list;          // [1]

    void push(Animal& ref) {                             // [2]  
        list.push_back(std::make_shared<Animal>(ref));
    }

    void push(std::shared_ptr<Animal> shared_ptr) {
        list.push_back(shared_ptr);
    }
};

int main() {

    Bird magpie;
    std::shared_ptr<Mammal> dog_ptr (new Mammal());
    AnimalList list;

    list.push(magpie);       // [3]
    list.push(dog_ptr);      // [4]

    //std::cout << std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Bird>(list.list[0])->get_type() << "\n";    //[5] Segmentation fault
    std::cout << std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Mammal>(list.list[1])->get_type() << "\n";    //[6] Mammal

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the ownership actually shared, or could you use `unique_ptr`?

Comment: @user997112 It seems that I cannot store a `unique_ptr` of a derived type in a container that is declared to store unique pointers of the base type.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a reference to an object in the stack and make a shared pointer out of it you tell the system “hey I want two owners to control this.” That means two things will try to kill the object, which is not ok. There should only be one owner for each object. If you want a shared pointer the object must be constructed in a way that nothing else owns it.

Either you need to pass on a shared pointer, make a copy, or create the object dynamically some other way. Then only one thing owns the object and handles its destruction.

Comment: According the solution (and errors) pointed out by songyanyao, putting aside the dynamic casting issue, making a shared pointer from a reference is possible, not ideal though. Your answer, however, seems to invalidate that solution. Could you please substantiate it by, perhaps, examples?  The "two owner" comment, in particular, is confusing to me. Here `ref` in `push(Bird& ref)` is local to this function and is thus deleted when `push` exits.

Comment: @XaviervandenBosch the actual object is local to `main` and it will be destroyed there when it’s out of scope. But it will also be destroyed when the shared pointer goes out of scope. You can test it easily by making a function that has a local object, making a shared pointer of it, and checking how the destructor is called. The workaround that was presented in another answer makes a copy so there is no issue, there is just two objects owned by two parents, which is very different.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you didn't invalidate line [2] or songyanyao's answer on copy-constructing a shared pointer out of reference, but rather pointed out that (locally) creating a shared pointer out of a reference to a variable in the same scope is actually creating the "two owners" situation.

Comment: @XaviervandenBosch there’s nothing wrong with creating a copy, if you want a copy. Usually that’s not what’s wanted since you want a single object accessible from several places and don’t want the performance, memory usage, possible fragmentation etc may come with it. And the problem isn’t “same scope”, it’s any scope.

Comment: Much advised. You suggestion is somehow aligned with songyanyao's recommendation of using shared pointer from the very beginning. Honestly, the interface would be rather busy, if not too ugly, with `std::shared_ptr` everywhere. Any suggestions or remedy on that? Or, "just get used to it".

Answer (score 2):

Given `std::make_shared<Animal>(ref)`, you're creating an `std::shared_ptr` pointing an `Animal`, which is copied-constructed from `ref`. Then the dynamic cast fails and `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Bird>(list.list[0])` returns a null pointer.

You need to create the `std::shared_ptr` pointing to `Bird` from the beginning. E.g.

```
void push(Bird& ref) {                             // [2]  
    list.push_back(std::make_shared<Bird>(ref));
}
```

BTW: The destructor of `Animal` should be marked as `virtual`.

Comment: So, basically you are suggesting that (1) either to specialise the interface of `push` method, such as adding `push(Fish&)`, `push(Bird&)` etc, or (2) to unify the interface to `push(std::shared_ptr<Animal>)` and only push shared pointers from the very beginning.

Comment: @XaviervandenBosch (2) seems better to me. What kind of `std::shared_ptr` is `push`ed should be determined by the caller side.